# UILocalNotification is not working in my device

Tags: iphone, ios, ipad, uilocalnotification

Here is the code that I have used in my application to generate local notification:

```
 UILocalNotification *aNotification = [[UILocalNotification alloc] init];
 if (aNotification == nil)
 {
     NSLog(@"localNotif");
     return;
 }

 NSDateFormatter *dateFormatter = [[NSDateFormatter alloc] init];
 [dateFormatter setDateFormat:@"yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss"];
 NSTimeZone *sourceTimeZone = [NSTimeZone timeZoneForSecondsFromGMT:19800];
 [dateFormatter setTimeZone:sourceTimeZone];
 NSDate *sourceDate = [dateFormatter dateFromString:@"2013-02-16 15:00:00"];

 NSTimeZone* destinationTimeZone = [NSTimeZone systemTimeZone];
 NSInteger destinationGMTOffset = [destinationTimeZone secondsFromGMTForDate:sourceDate];
 NSTimeInterval interval = destinationGMTOffset;
 NSDate* destinationDate = [[NSDate alloc] initWithTimeInterval:interval sinceDate:sourceDate];
 aNotification.fireDate = destinationDate;
 aNotification.timeZone = [NSTimeZone defaultTimeZone];

 NSLog(@"destinationDate %@",destinationDate);

 aNotification.alertBody = @"About To Start";
 aNotification.alertAction = @"View";
 [[UIApplication sharedApplication] scheduleLocalNotification:aNotification];
 [dateFormatter release];
 [destinationDate release];
 [aNotification release];
```

But when I test it in device by changing the date and time from Settings application, the event is not firing. What am I doing wrong?

When I print `destinationDate` in console it is coming like this:

```
destinationDate 2013-02-16 15:00:00 +0000
```

Comment: what time you are setting... make NSLog in appdelegate, receive notification code..

Comment: I am not receiving notification only to print it in NSLog.

Comment: Hi, I m struggle with same situation. One simple ques? Suppose, I have set notification for tomorrow at 11 AM. Then close the app. And go to setting date-time, and changed tomorrow and time 10:55 AM. So, after 5 min, can I get notification or not? Currently I am not getting any notification. Can you please help? and share your idea. Many Thanks.